# How to fix bind configuration when nothing seems to work

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I'm configuring BIND to host a nameserver for a domain name. I didn't want to use the domain registrar because this domain (which I don't own personally) is hosted on Hover, and was migrated from enom and the management for their nameserver through the web portal seems to be broken (new A records have no affect even after waiting days for DNS propagation).

I've looked at 5 different references online on how to configure BIND. Right now I'm trying to get the simplest possible configuration to work as to avoid complications.

For the sake of this question `1.2.3.4` is my server's IP address and `mywebsite.com` is my domain name.

I have a file at `/var/named/ns1.mywebsite.com.db` with these contents:

```
$TTL 300
@ IN SOA ns1.mywebsite.com. admin.mywebsite.com. (
  3
  3600
  1800
  604800
  86400
)

@ IN NS ns1.mywebsite.com.
ns1 IN A 1.2.3.4
www IN A 1.2.3.4
gitlab IN A 1.2.3.4
```

I added this zone to my `named.conf` file:

```
zone "ns1.mywebsite.com" IN {
  type master;
  file "ns1.mywebsite.com.db";
  allow-update { none; };
  allow-query { any; };
};
```

When I start the `named` service it produces this useless error message:

```
ns1.mywebsite.com.db:12: ignoring out-of-zone data (mywebsite.com)
ns1.mywebsite.com.db:14: ignoring out-of-zone data (www.mywebsite.com)
ns1.mywebsite.com.db:15: ignoring out-of-zone data (gitlab.mywebsite.com)
zone ns1.mywebsite.com/IN: has no NS records
zone ns1.mywebsite.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/ns1.mywebsite.com/IN: bad zone
```

I know the title of my question isn't ideal. I have a feeling the answer will suggest a better title so I'll edit it later.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out one of the sources I looked at had the nameserver in the zone entry (i.e. "ns1.example.com" instead of "example.com"), and this is incorrect.